# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

I've been trying to debug this issue for a bit now, and searching SO and other websites I haven't been able to find a solution. I've checked all versions of the dependencies in my *pom.xml* and made sure they are compatible with grizzly2, and I've also verified that it is being imported. However, Java is still printing out this error upon run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/utilities/Binder;)V
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:334)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:122)
at com.kyrahosting.daemon.Main.startServer(Main.java:30)
at com.kyrahosting.daemon.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Here is my pom.xml:
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.kyrapanel.daemon</groupId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>KyraPanel Daemon</name>
<artifactId>KyraDaemon</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- any other plugins -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.kyrahosting.daemon.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.17</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't mix your Jersey versions

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Which one is different? Fix it.

And get rid of this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.30</version>
</dependency>
```

`jersey-container-grizzly2-http` already pulls in everything you need for Grizzly.

As an aside, the error says nothing about "GrizzlyHttpServerFactory doens't exist". It's saying that there is no such method (in this case constructor)

```
public ApplicationHandler(Application application, Binder binder) {}
```

That's how you read this

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/utilities/Binder;)V
```

The reason you would get this error when mixing versions is because say some class in Jersey 2.25.1 is trying to call the constructor mentioned above. But in version 2.9.1 this constructor doesn't exist. Say it wasn't added til a later version. But when loading classes, the `ApplicationHandler` from 2.9.1 is loaded, instead of the one from 2.25.1. So now you have the wrong `ApplicationHandler` version loaded. Hence the error; there's no such constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer, this did the trick. Can't believe I didn't catch that version!

Comment: The most important part of this answer is the bit where it says: `Don't mix your Jersey versions`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the versions and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing an issue similar to the one asked here with my Spring Boot Application. My application was unable to find  *LocalizationMessages* class under *org.glassfish.jersey.internal* in place of *org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.* with the same error *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError* .

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String**

`2021-09-20 15:27:47.927 INFO 11 --- [http-nio-9070-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;] with root cause`

The irony is that the same set of dependencies worked fine on a java maven project. On getting the dependency tree `mvn dependency:tree` for java project I was able to get class **org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages** but it was missing on the dependency tree for Spring Boot Project.

***Following Issues observed:***

1. The Jar created by Spring Boot was not containing the dependency when I was using spring-boot-maven-plugin with version 2.4.3

   ```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </plugin>
   ```
2. When I was trying to create a shaded jar with the above version then I was getting error for all the Transformer implementation I was using. Error ex: `Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade for parameter resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer`
3. I changed the version to `1.5.8.RELEASE` and then the shaded jar compilation went through.
4. I replaced the default Spring Boot Application Plugin with the shaded jar Plugin.

**Default Spring Boot Application Plugin**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.rohit.agrawal.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Shaded Jar Plugin I used to resolve error**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.rohit.agrawal.Application</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Please see that here** `spring-boot-version` **is 1.5.8.RELEASE**

***Now the Jar has the required class:***

```
rohiagra-mac:faw-qa-api rohiagra$ jar -tvf target/faw-qa-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep "org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages"
 42097 Tue Sep 21 18:01:54 IST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/LocalizationMessages.class
   268 Tue Sep 21 18:01:56 IST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/LocalizationMessages$1.class
  1272 Tue Sep 21 18:01:56 IST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/LocalizationMessages$BundleSupplier.class
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have updated with Answer with the clarity and also quoted the output. The core issue or the problem is same. The solution is same for the question asked here and the one I had faced.

Comment: it helped me created shaded jar for spring-boot application and I was able to see dependent class.

Answer (score 0):

In Dec.2017, this set of Maven dependencies worked fine for me to start Jetty with RS.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.26-b03</version>
    </dependency>
```